# What is the AutoFac SingleInstance() in Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, autofac

I have inherited some Autofac code. Not quite familiar with it.

I can see `.SingleInstance()` everywhere. What are these equivalent statements in Unity?

```
builder.RegisterType<VehicleRepository>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<UserStore<User>>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces<IUserStore<User>>, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Both DI Framework have `RegisterType` but the syntax are so different. I am trying to find some article about them. Please paste here some links if you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It registers as a singleton, which I believe is ContainerControlledLifetimeManager in Unity.

https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx

Comment: So I assume it would be `container.RegisterType<VehicleRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());` and `container.RegisterType<IUserStore<User>, UserStore<User>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());` Isn't it?